# The best way to store GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file for access to my bigquery.

Locally I set `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path-to-file>.json` and all works fine.

What about my server on AWS?

I use docker and ECS with Task Definition and all of my other env variables is setup when I create/update Task definition, but I cant store this json file there.

So ho can I access path to my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file on my server envs, where I should store it?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am in the same situation.

Comment: @JeromeDevost I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I can`t find any solution for this case yet.
So, I found a way to read data from json stored in my env.

In my case:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    json.loads(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON'))
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id)
```

Maybe it can help someone.